# Connecting to rtsp stream of ip camera using proxy

Tags: video-streaming, rtsp, ip-camera

For my application I am running computer vision software on a jetson device that is connected to an ip-camera. This jetson device is enclosed and I don't have any access to it to connect a screen.

My goal is to create a tool to aim my camera and configure a region of intrest on the image. For this I somehow need to be able to connect a webapplication to the ip-camera using the jetson device as a proxy. As I said I cannot connect a display to the jetson but I can connect to the jetson device using a wifi connection to my laptop.

What is a good way to be able to access the camera? At the moment I was looking into rtsp forwarding using gstreamer but rtsp is not supported in the browser or using WebRTC, but this seems really complex to setup and feels like overkill for the application.

Anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way you can get RTSP into the browser directly. You can use WebRTC or something like HLS or MSE.

[RTSPtoWeb](https://github.com/deepch/RTSPtoWeb) is one pre-built solution. Which protocol you use depends on your latency needs and if you want to hook into any existing software etc...